# How to import data from Excel into QTP

Tags: qtp

I am trying to write a script that could be used to import data from a sheet in excel into my QTP Data table.
Below is the script . But even though the script runs successfully, I cannot seem to get the data pop up in the data table. Any help is greatly appreciated.

datatable.Import Sheet "C:\Documents and settings\Administrator\Desktop\Book1.xlsx",Sheet1,Action1

Comment: Are you executing the script, and, after execution, looking for the sheet in the DataTable view? Sheets created by Import are runtime-only, i.e. the design-time table sheets remain unchanged.

Comment: If you step over the Import statement with the debugger, you should be able to see the sheet as long as script execution hasn´t ended.

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that if you ever want to change the design-time data table (not the run-time table that you modify using the 'DataTable.Import' statement), the default implementation in QTP/UFT is to have a file called 'default.xls' that is stored in the test's folder (remember, QTP tests are not files... they are folders containing a collection of many files).  Open that file directly in Excel and enjoy a wide range of opportunities to insert and update your data.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think .Import Sheet method supports files of .xlsx format. Try it with a .xls file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
Public Function ImportExcelSheet(ByVal EXCEL_PATH,ByVal EXCEL_SOURCE_SHEET,ByVal DT_DEST_SHEET)
    On Error Resume Next
    sSheetName = DataTable.DeleteSheet(DT_DEST_SHEET)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Err.Clear
    DataTable.AddSheet DT_DEST_SHEET
    DataTable.ImportSheet EXCEL_PATH,EXCEL_SOURCE_SHEET,DT_DEST_SHEET
End Function
```